# Should i mock List for stream operations?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4

I have a line of code in function which applies stream operations on an `ArrayList` as:

```
List<Entity> list = xyz(); 

long result = list.stream().map(n -> n.getData()).filter(n -> n == 1).count();
```

Now when i write a test for this method should i do like:

```
@Mock
private List<Entity> list;

//inside the test method
when(list.stream().map(any()).filter(any()).count()).thenReturn(someValue);
```

What is coming to my mind is that when we are calling stream operations in our code, we are basically going out of our class to call these functions. Since it is unit testing we should remain inside our module. Please clarify if i have some misconceptions. If we do not need to mock `List`, then why?

Comment: no. You should rather mock xyz()

Comment: yeah that is done. I was really concerned about the stream operations only. If we don't need to mock List then why? Basically we are going outside our module.

Comment: ehm ... no? the streaming of the list is all within that method. it's just the xyz() call that goes beyond the scope

Comment: The thing which is confusing me is that stream() is a method of `ArrayList` and not our own class. That is why it pops to my mind that we are going out of our class.

Comment: in that case, String is also another class, would you go mock "test".equals(value) as well? you only need to mock anything, if you can't get the value. you have the value of the list, because that is returned by xyz(), there is no need to mock anything.

Comment: That is satisfying answer...thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* mock the list but it's probably way more trouble than it's worth. The list and stream interfaces are so large that it's difficult to mock them without either mocking every method (no thanks) or mocking only the methods that you use, which means you'd be relying on knowing internal implementation details of the method that you're testing. The latter leads to fragile tests. It's best to write a test that doesn't care about implementation details, just inputs and outputs.

Mocking should be used when it's prohibitively hard to create a proper version of the object, or when you want to provide isolation for the test. Lists are not hard to create, and they are so well-tested that mocking them does not really provide any value for the increased isolation.

Just create a list normally.

```
list = Arrays.asList(new Entity(1), new Entity(2), new Entity(1));
```

In this case, you would assert the result of the method to be 2.

You may get some mileage out of mocking the Entity, however e.g.

```
Mockito.when(Entity.getData()).thenReturn(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you dont really care about the internal working of that stream operations, you just care about its outcome.

In my opinion you should extract that logic to some other specialized class which would have a public method accepting the list and returning the count.

Then you could use that class as a dependency and mock its count method:

```
// the impl

private DataCounter dataCounter;

...

List<Entity> list = xyz(); 

long result = dataCounter.count(list);

// test class

@Mock
private DataCounter dataCounter;

//inside the test method
when(dataCounter.count(Mockito.any(List.class)).thenReturn(Mockito.eq(someValue));
```